# How I need to use these CALLs correctly?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I've used first *CALL* after *LOAD CSV* for splitting transactions and second for creating relations between two types of nodes - *Legal_Entity* and *Natural_Person*. *SYSTEM* node is my analog for dicts contains associations between numbers - numeric interpretations of relations - and text of these relations.

In relation to is relation type for *Legal_Entity* or for *Natural_Person* I need to connect others nodes (a.e., if code is 100 it means **LEGAL-LEGAL** connection with text "**has a division**". If code is 110 it means **LEGAL-PHYSICAL** connection with text "**founded by**").

Now I need to make a request that would determine which type of node the connection is being built to and build it accordingly.

If it's needed I can add more clarify info for used data.

```
:auto LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///CSVs/связи_фикс_все.csv' as row
call {
    with row

    match (legal:Legal_Entity {hid_party: row['first_related_hid']})
    match (sys:SYSTEM) 
    with sys, legal,
        row, 
        sys['type_' + tostring(row['id_relation_type'])] as relation_data, 
        sys[row['second_related_type']] as rel_type

        CALL {
            WITH rel_type, relation_data, row, legal
            WITH rel_type, relation_data, row, legal
            WHERE rel_type = 'Legal_Entity'
            match (legal_2:Legal_Entity {hid_party : row['second_related_hid']})
    
            CALL apoc.create.relationship(legal, relation_data[1], NULL, legal_2) YIELD rel1
            CALL apoc.create.relationship(legal_2, relation_data[3], NULL, legal) YIELD rel2
            return rel_type as rel_type_2

            UNION

            WITH rel_type, relation_data, row, legal
            WITH rel_type, relation_data, row, legal
            WHERE rel_type = 'Natural_Person'
            match (natural:Legal_Entity {hid_party : row['second_related_hid']})
    
            CALL apoc.create.relationship(legal, relation_data[1], NULL, natural) YIELD rel1
            CALL apoc.create.relationship(natural, relation_data[3], NULL, legal) YIELD rel2
            return rel_type as rel_type_2
    } return rel_type_2

} IN TRANSACTIONS of 10 rows
```

Comment: what seems to be the problem=

Comment: @TomažBratanič This query raises an error. Maybe it cans be shortly and more effectively then I did. I want to get solution of raised error (**Query cannot conclude with CALL**) OR other way to solve the task. IDK what may be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subqueries seem to be behaving weird when you have them nested. You can simply use `PERIODIC COMMIT` if you want to import data in batches and get rid of the top-level subquery.

```
:auto USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///CSVs/связи_фикс_все.csv' as row
with row

MERGE (legal:Legal_Entity {hid_party: row['first_related_hid']})
MERGE (sys:SYSTEM) 
with sys, legal,
    row, 
    sys['type_' + tostring(row['id_relation_type'])] as relation_data, 
    sys[row['second_related_type']] as rel_type

    CALL {
        WITH rel_type, relation_data, row, legal
        WITH rel_type, relation_data, row, legal
        WHERE rel_type = 'Legal_Entity'
        match (legal_2:Legal_Entity {hid_party : row['second_related_hid']})

        CALL apoc.create.relationship(legal, relation_data[1], NULL, legal_2) YIELD rel AS rel1
        CALL apoc.create.relationship(legal_2, relation_data[3], NULL, legal) YIELD rel AS rel2
        return rel_type as rel_type_2

        UNION

        WITH rel_type, relation_data, row, legal
        WITH rel_type, relation_data, row, legal
        WHERE rel_type = 'Natural_Person'
        match (natural:Legal_Entity {hid_party : row['second_related_hid']})

        CALL apoc.create.relationship(legal, relation_data[1], NULL, natural) YIELD rel AS rel1
        CALL apoc.create.relationship(natural, relation_data[3], NULL, legal) YIELD rel AS rel2
        return rel_type as rel_type_2
}
RETURN distinct 'done'
```